PHP script not working
We have a 3rd party module that needs PHP script to customize the upload of a stock update.
Like the file we get it has SKU name with space "-" and "/". But the SKU in MAgento do not.
So i created a script that removes "/" and "-" and another script that trims the cell.
Each script works sepretly but not together. Anyone that can help me with what is wrong?
<?php
 /* Your custom script */
return str_replace(['/','-','.',','],'', $self);
return trim($cell [0]);


As per your code, You have added 2 return statement so second line code will never get executed.
Instead of this create a variable and last line should return final output

The issue with your script is that you have two return statements one after the other. In PHP, once a return statement is executed, the function exits, and any code after the first return will not be executed.
Here’s your modified code as below,
<?php
/* Your custom script */
$cleanedCell = str_replace(['/','-','.',','], '', $cell[0]);
return trim($cleanedCell);

